# How can I access properties from older then calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I used to code like this, and eventually found myself in a callback hell.

```
 Redis.get("boo", (res1) => {
      Redis.get(res1, (res2) => {
          console.log(res1);
          console.log(res2);
      });
 });
```

Howeever, when I do it like this:

```
Redis.getAsync("boo)
.then(res1 => {
    return Redis.getAsync(res1);
})
.then(res2 => {
    console.log(res1) // undefined
});
```

I cannot access `res1` any longer. Passing parameters on each return feels dirty.

Any elegant solutions to this issue?

Comment: Another (dirty) solution would be to declare `res1` in the scope of the whole function. Based on how closure work, I doubt there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @DrakaSAN: Very dirty indeed. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Redis.getAsync("boo")
.then(res1 => {
    return Redis.getAsync(res1).then(res2 => ({res1, res2}));
})
.then(({res1, res2}) => {
    console.log(res1, res2);
});
```

Comment: This will lead back to callback hell, and OP chosed Promise to prevent exactly that.

Comment: how is this callback hell? I almost posted exactly the same answer :p so I'm biased

Comment: calback hell is when you go with callbacks deeper and deeper. You can't refuse callbacks at all, but you can create more clear code.

Comment: is that shorthand syntax supported in nodejs yet? last time I checked (a long time ago) I don't think it worked

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it has been for a while (assuming you mean the arrow function). Destructuring not so much.

Comment: @DrakaSAN This isn't close to callback hell, since you're just passing the scope of `res1` into the next chain.

Comment: @DrakaSAN: no, there is no callback hell here, because you have at most two nested functions.

Comment: (of course, [I'm slightly biased as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250693/1048572))

Comment: I meant the shorthand object assignment

Comment: @Bergi @BenFortune: Right, I misread the code and thought he was chaining the `then` inside one another. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** officially supported but...

What about using `aync`/`await` if you are feeling adventurous and happy to use babel.

```
async function foo() {
  const res1 = await Redis.getAsync("boo")
  const res2 = await Redis.getAsync(res1)
}
```